# Java or Scala libraries for stream parsers

Tags: java, scala, parsing

As far as I understand Scala parser combinators require the whole file to be in memory and it's not quite practical for files tens of gigabytes in size. Anyway, parser combinator library is way more powerful than needed for task at hand so I'm thinking about rolling out simple FSA parser. Are there some libraries for this or there's no other way except wall of text with multiple `switch`es?

Comment: Antlr is good tool to generate parsers. As far as I know, it's possible to use streaming to parse possibly infinite character stream.

Comment: Reading scaladoc, a parser combinator is applied on a `Reader[Elem]`. Even if this one is usually inited from a string, it may be possible to do it in a streaming way (never tried).

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand Scala parser combinators require the whole file
>   to be in memory and it's not quite practical for files tens of
>   gigabytes in size

If you need to parse a huge file, you can use a `BufferedReader` and invoke `parseAll` with that reader. Something like this:

```
val bufferedReader: BufferedReader = ???
val myResult = MyParser.parseAll(MyParser.rootParser, bufferedReader)
```

This way the file is read in chunks so that you shouldn't be bothered to run out of memory.

Alternatively, you could create a `PagedSeqReader` from a `bufferedSource` if you need a reader specific to the parser combinators API.

```
val rdr = new PagedSeqReader(PagedSeq.fromReader(Source.fromFile(new File("huge_file")).bufferedReader()))
```